# How can I pass a base64 image to tensorflow JS?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

- I'm using `tensorflow JS` to do image classification.
- I store training images in the browser indexDB in data format (aka data `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...`)

When I train, I use this function which is supposed to convert my data IMG to a tensor.

```js
const imageToTensor = (imageData: string) => {
    // convert base64 to Image for the fromPixels
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = imageData
    img.width = 224
    img.height = 224

    const imageFeatures = tf.tidy(function () {
        const imageAsTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img)
        imageAsTensor.print()
        return imageAsTensor
    })
    return imageFeatures
}
```

But my `imageAsTensor.print()` is showing me just a bunch of 000

```
Tensor
    [[[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      ...,
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      ...,
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      ...,
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]],

     ...
     [[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      ...,
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      ...,
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      ...,
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Can't seem to see what I am doing wrong. Am I missing an await or something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [OBOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), base++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tensor is empty because at that point in the code, image is empty.

`HTMLImageElement` is **NOT** ready as soon as you assign to its `src` property, you need to wait for `onDataLoaded` or equivalent event.